# How to append data in data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

 #put all item in this array
response = requests.get('http://smartcatalog.emo-milano.com/it/espositore/a-mannesmann-maschinenfabrik-gmbh')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table=soup.find_all('table', class_='expo-table general-color')
for row in table:
         for up in row.find_all('td'):
             text_list = [text for text in up.stripped_strings]
             print(text_list)
```

These code is working good and they will get me the correct output but they will not give output in these format as you seen below  I want output in these format can you help me

```
Indirizzo   Bliedinghauserstrasse 27
Città        Remscheid
Nazionalità   Germania
Sito web      www.amannesmann.de
Stand         Pad. 3 E14 F11
Telefono      +492191989-0
Fax          +492191989-201
E-mail       sales@mannesmann.de
Membro di     Cecimo
Social
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.get_text()` method to extract text and use parameters to avoid whitespaces and give extra space using `separator`

```
data=table.find_all("tr")
for i in data:
    print(i.get_text(strip=True,separator=" "))
```

Output:

```
Indirizzo Bliedinghauserstrasse 27
Città Remscheid
...
```

Comment: brother they give me error you are treating list of  element like single element

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` has a builtin html table scraper, so you can run:

```
df = pd.read_html('http://smartcatalog.emo-milano.com/it/espositore/a-mannesmann-maschinenfabrik-gmbh')
```

This returns a list of all tables on the page as dataframes, you can access your data with `df[0]`:

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Indirizzo | Bliedinghauserstrasse 27 |
| 1 | Città | Remscheid |
| 2 | Nazionalità | Germania |
| 3 | Sito web | [www.amannesmann.de](http://www.amannesmann.de) |
| 4 | Stand | Pad. 3 E14 F11 |
| 5 | Telefono | +492191989-0 |
| 6 | Fax | +492191989-201 |
| 7 | E-mail | sales@mannesmann.de |
| 8 | Membro di | nan |
| 9 | Social | nan |

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting `<td>`, select `<tr>` and use `.stripped_strings` on it to get the row wise data and then append them to the Dataframe.

Here is the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

#put all item in this array
temp = []
response = requests.get('http://smartcatalog.emo-milano.com/it/espositore/a-mannesmann-maschinenfabrik-gmbh')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table=soup.find_all('table', class_='expo-table general-color')
for row in table:
    for up in row.find_all('tr'):
        temp.append([text for text in up.stripped_strings])

df = pd.DataFrame(temp)
print(df)
```

```
             0                         1
0    Indirizzo  Bliedinghauserstrasse 27
1        Città                 Remscheid
2  Nazionalità                  Germania
3     Sito web        www.amannesmann.de
4        Stand            Pad. 3 E14 F11
5     Telefono              +492191989-0
6          Fax            +492191989-201
7       E-mail       sales@mannesmann.de
8    Membro di                      None
9       Social                      None
```